# SKCameraNode and Aspect Ratio

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skcameranode

I'm making a game and would like to create a universal scene size. Its height will be 2048, for example. The width of the level will be different depending on the level.

I want the height of the level (the play area) to fit completely on the screen of the device, regardless of the device whatever it is (iPhone, iPad).

GameViewController:

```
scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
```

SKScene:

```
let cameraNode = SKCameraNode ()
let background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Background")



override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    background.size = CGSize(width: 2048, height: 1536)
    background.position = CGPoint(x: 1024, y: 768)
    addChild(background)

    cameraNode.position = CGPoint(x: background.size.width / 2,
                                  y: background.size.height / 2)


    addChild(cameraNode)
    camera = cameraNode
}

override func didChangeSize(_ oldSize: CGSize) {
        let screenHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height
        let backgroundHeight = background.size.height
        let scaleFactor = backgroundHeight / screenHeight
        cameraNode.setScale(scaleFactor)
    }
```

Comment: are you allowing device rotation in iOS? if not, is the orientation landscape or portrait? and are you supporting window resize in macOS? supporting all those things is possible but makes the solution more difficult.

Comment: App for iPhone and iPad. Landscape orientation only.

Answer (score 0):

different iOS devices will have dramatically different sizes. hence you need to scale your camera based on the size of the screen and the size of your background image.

GameViewController

```
scene.scaleMode = .resizeFill
```

SKScene

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    let cameraNode = SKCameraNode()
    let background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "background")
    
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        //set up camera note
        self.addChild(cameraNode)
        self.camera = cameraNode
        
        //add background image
        self.addChild(background)
    }
    
    override func didChangeSize(_ oldSize: CGSize) {
        //calculate scale factor based on screen size and image size
        let screen_height = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height
        let background_height = background.size.height
        let scale_factor = background_height/screen_height
        cameraNode.setScale(scale_factor) //scale the camera accordingly
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this method didn't work.
I have a scene (2048x1536) and background (same size)
I did everything exactly as stated in the answer. But the camera  goes outside the play area. I also wrote position for SKNode. Its perfectly in the center of the gamescene (x: 1024, y: 768)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: By the way...

I came up with the idea that you can zoom the camera on this object. That is, the camera must capture the entire object of the scene and not go beyond it. Due to this, the upper part of the scene will always fit completely on the screen of any device. But, unfortunately, I don't understand how it can be implemented.

Comment: show me the code you're using to create your scene in the `GameViewController` .. and/or post a zip somewhere of the whole project. how are you setting `scene.size` and `scene.scaleMode`?

Comment: change your scaleMode to `.resizeFill`. also if you resize and reposition your background and camera it will affect the scale_factor. so delete the three lines where you set `background.size` and `background.position` and `cameraNode.position`